# What can cause a slight pattern/noise in a solid color on a monitor?

Tags: display, hdmi

I've noticed that my display with HDMI input shows a very slight, just barely visible pattern on dark colors. Sometimes it's vertical lines, sometimes it's a plaid-like square pattern, sometimes it's like random noise. But these patterns don't animate like noise on a TV, they're static as long as the image is static.

I tried playing around in Photoshop with 1 bit changes in colors and I managed to produce different patterns. It's very hard to make a good photo of, but here's the test pattern image:

[image: pls no 50 shades of grey jokes]

and here are some close-up photos of the top left quadrant:

[image]
[image]

Patterns change around between the same cells in other quadrants due to 1 bit color change (slightly red/green/blue).

I didn't notice such a pattern going on my older d-sub display (if I'm not mistaken that was analog type video signal instead of digital).

Is this some HDMI signal side-effect?  Or is the display causing this? Or is this my graphics card? I don't have another comparable display to test this out on.

Comment: Looks like dithering to me.

Comment: could it be an effect of a non-default color profile?

Comment: Or of display circuitry that doesn't support full 24-bit color.

Comment: When I list all display modes, it only shows 16 bit and 32 bit. I remember a time when I had a 24 bit mode on some very old pc. I guess I can't test it on this one.

Comment: That's the video driver, though. Putting the driver into 32-bit mode should let you see if your display supports it.

Comment: I've been using it in 32 bit mode for years. I checked out 16 bit mode just now and it looks very bad. If I play around with Digital Vibrance slider, it changes the colors and patterns. Also I just found out I have High Bandwidth Digital Content Protection capability now (probably because I'm now using the HDMI port instead of d-sub). Could this be a side effect of that?

Comment: Extremely unlikely. What is the brand and model of the display?

Comment: display is Acer G246HL bbid

Comment: Did you try to change port, like DisplayPort or DVI?

Comment: @spike_66 there is only 1 HDMI input on this monitor

Comment: I'm aware of this, but your monitor also has a DVI and a VGA port.

Comment: oh sorry I misread it as some other question. There are also 1 d-sub and 1 DVI socket on  the back. But I don't have any other cables so I can't test them.